# magento 1.9.2.2 not saving product programmatically

Tags: product, import, ce-1.9.2.2

i have created a script to import configurable product with its associated products. it was working fine in magento 1.9.0.1 .after i updated my magento to latest version(1.9.2.2) the script is not working.

it showing error while calling `$product->save();`

the snippet of displaying error -
`Invalid method Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule::loadProductRules(Array
(
    [0] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object
        (
            [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_product
            [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_product
            [_eventObject:protected] => product
            [_canAffectOptions:protected] => 
            [_typeInstance:protected] => 
            [_typeInstanceSingleton:protected] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple Object
                (
                    [_product:protected] => 
                    [_typeId:protected] => 
                    [_setAttributes:protected] => 
                    [_editableAttributes:protected] => 
                    [_isComposite:protected] => 
                    [_canConfigure:protected] => 
                    [_canUseQtyDecimals:protected] => 1
                    [_storeFilter:protected] => 
                    [_fileQueue:protected] => Array
                        (
                        ))`

Snippet of Code in Script
`$sProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$sProduct -> setName($product['name']);
                                $sProduct -> setSku($product['sku']);
                                $sProduct -> setWeight($product['weight']);
                                $sProduct -> setAttributeSetId($product['attribute_set_id']);
                                $sProduct -> setDescription($product['description']);
                                $sProduct -> setShortDescription($product['short_description']);
                                $sProduct -> setTypeId($product['type_id']) -> setWebsiteIds(array(1)) -> setStatus($product['status']) -> setVisibility($product['visibility']) -> setTaxClassId($product['tax_class_id']);
                                $sProduct -> setPrice($product['price']);
                                $sProduct -> setStockData($product['stock_data']);
                                $sProduct -> setCategoryId($product['category_ids']);
                                $optionId = $this -> getOptionId('size', $product['size']);
                                $sProduct -> setData('size', $optionId);
                                $optionIdcolor = $this -> getOptionId('color', $product['color']);
                                $sProduct -> setData('color', $optionIdcolor);
                                $mode = array("small_image", "thumbnail", "image");
                                $mode1 = array();
                                $imges = explode(',',$product['img']);
                                $ij = 0;
                                foreach ($imges as $nml) {
                                    $imges[$ij] = $nml.'.jpg';
                                    $ij++;
                                }
                                $a = 0;
                                foreach ($imges as $im) {
                                    $img = $mediaDir.'/import/'.$im;
                                    Mage::log($img);
                                    if ($a == 0) {
                                        Mage::log($im);
                                        if (file_exists($img)) {
                                            $sProduct -> addImageToMediaGallery($img, $mode, false, false);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        if(substr($im, 0, 1) == ' ')
                                            {
                                                $im = substr($im, 1);
                                            }
                                        Mage::log($im);
                                        if (file_exists($img)) {
                                            $sProduct -> addImageToMediaGallery($img, $mode1, false, false);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $a++;
                                }
$sProduct->save();`

i am getting correct values while `print_r($sProduct)` but it shows error while saving

Comment: Share your code as well

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar i have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the proper solution for the issue. it was giving error because during updation some of magento's core files were not downloaded properly .
So i replaced the whole core folder with magento's latest version core folder and now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Try bellow script**

```
$sProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

$optionId = $this->getOptionId('size', $product['size']);
$optionIdcolor = $this->getOptionId('color', $product['color']);

$productData = array(
    'size' => $optionId,
    'color' => $optionIdcolor,
);
$mode = array("small_image", "thumbnail", "image");
$mode1 = array();


$sProduct->setName($product['name']);
$sProduct->setSku($product['sku']);
$sProduct->setWeight($product['weight']);
$sProduct->setAttributeSetId($product['attribute_set_id']);
$sProduct->setDescription($product['description']);
$sProduct->setShortDescription($product['short_description']);
$sProduct->setTypeId($product['type_id']);
$sProduct->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
$sProduct->setStatus($product['status']);
$sProduct->setVisibility($product['visibility']);
$sProduct->setTaxClassId($product['tax_class_id']);
$sProduct->setPrice($product['price']);
$sProduct->setStockData($product['stock_data']);
$sProduct->setCategoryIds($product['category_ids']);
$sProduct->setMediaGallery(array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
$sProduct->setData($productData);


$imges = explode(',',$product['img']);
$ij = 0;
foreach ($imges as $nml) {
    $imges[$ij] = $nml.'.jpg';
    $ij++;
}
$a = 0;
foreach ($imges as $im) {
    $img = $mediaDir.'/import/'.$im;
    Mage::log($img);
    if ($a == 0) {
        Mage::log($im);
        if (file_exists($img)) {
            $sProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($img, $mode, false, false);
        }
    } else {
        if(substr($im, 0, 1) == ' ')
            {
                $im = substr($im, 1);
            }
        Mage::log($im);
        if (file_exists($img)) {
            $sProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($img, $mode1, false, false);
        }
    }
    $a++;
}

try {
    $sProduct->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: no change same result

Comment: can you share error?

Comment: it showing the same error which  i mentioned above.

Comment: If your tried to create product to admin end then got same error. First check in admin side

Comment: no its not working either